# How to add only new items to array ReactNative

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm working with Bluetooth in my ReactNative app. I'm trying to create UI for discovered devices. For working with BT I use library `react-native-ble-plx` and method:

```
startDeviceScan(
      UUIDs: UUID[] | null,
      options: ScanOptions | null,
      listener: (error: BleError | null, scannedDevice: Device | null) => void
    ): void
```

and I use array in such way:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    devices: [],
  };
....

}
```

and add item to array of devices:

```
BleManager.startDeviceScan(
          null,
          {
            allowDuplicates: false,
          },
          async (error, device) => {
            if (error) {
              console.log(error.reason);
              _BleManager.stopDeviceScan();
            }
            if (device.localName != null) {
              if (!this.state.devices.includes(device)) {
                this.state.devices.push(device);
              }
            }
          },
        );
```

but here I see that my check `includes` does not work and check that item is in array does not help. How I can check that I already have some items in the array, or it can be done in another way?

Comment: You should not use the device name. Use the device identifier.

Comment: but I add unique item like device, it has ID I think and two objects will be different, or in JS it does not work like in java/kotlin/swift?

Comment: I meant the string value of the Bluetooth peripheral `identifier`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

device is object and devices is your array of objects, you can not check if devices array contains device object or not with `includes` method. You can check with this function as shown below.

```
const isDeviceInclude = (device) => {
  if (this.state.devices.filter(e => e.id === device.id).length > 0) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: And we also can return result of condition without if condition, right?

Comment: Yes, you can without if condition.